# Mongodb node.js sum of key values of all the document in the collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb

this is my cart collection which is having a price key. In my node.js code I want to view sum of price of both the documents. I tried using aggregate but didnt work

> cart collection

```
[
  {
    "_id": "57244d0a05dcf1d7151ede7f",
    "art_id": "57244c9505dcf1d7151ede7c",
    "artist_id": "5721a528c9d28cd51f014038",
    "user_id": "5721a528c9d28cd51f014038",
    "price": "90"
  },
  {
    "_id": "57244d1f05dcf1d7151ede80",
    "art_id": "57244c6105dcf1d7151ede7b",
    "artist_id": "5721a528c9d28cd51f014038",
    "user_id": "5721a528c9d28cd51f014038",
    "price": "150"
  }
]
```

> node.js code

```
function test(req, res, next) {
    db.users.findOne({
        _id: mongoskin.helper.toObjectID(req.session.user._id)
    }, function(err, user) {
        if (!user) {
            return res.status(400).send({
                status: '404 user not found'
            });
        }
        db.cart.find({
            user_id: req.session.user._id
        }).toArray(function(err, result) {
            if (err) return next(err);
            res.send(result)
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

to add all price can use **aggregate** like:

```
db.cart.aggregate(
        [
            {
                $group : {
                    _id : null,
                    totalPrice: { $sum: price }
                }
            }
        ]
    ).exec(function(error, result) {
        if (err) return next(err);
        res.send(result)
    });
```